# Как сделать консольный калькулятор на Python?

Tags: python

Я хочу сделать калькулятор на Python. Когда я смотрю в интернете как сделать калькулятор на Python, мне попадаются калькуляторы по типу введите первый, введите второй оператор. Как можно сделать так, чтоб можно было просто написать `2 + 2` и получить ответ?

Comment: Открыть консоль набрать `python` и ввести 2+2... в ответ получите 4.

Comment: а есть еще [bc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html)

Comment: [выбирайте на ваш вкус](https://github.com/search?l=Python&q=calculator+console&type=Repositories)

Comment: Если вы в интернетe не читаете, а смотрите, то есть такой [пример](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VbWLTR2JoIA).

Comment: Если хочется чего-то совсем мудрёного, то вот у меня есть один такой проект: https://gitflic.ru/project/nchistov/translate-into-reverse-polish-notation

Answer (score 10):

вот самый функциональный калькулятор:

```
print("результат: ", eval(input("Введите: ")))
```

но пользоваться им очень опасно

Answer (score 5):

На верхнем уровне уровне работает [read-eval-print loop (REPL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

`read` читает строку и разбивает её на токены - минимальные элементы имеющие самостоятельное значение. Простейший способ разбить на токены - регулярное выражение, которое выделит символы операций '+-*/()' и числа.

`print` печатает ответ.

`eval` по последовательности токенов вычисляет значение. Для вычисления используется [алгоритм сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).
[shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) - более подробное изложение, на английском.

Алгоритм сортировочной станции переводит обычную алгебраическую (её ещё называют инфиксной) запись в [обратную польскую нотацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) (постфиксную запись). Несколько примеров:

```
1 - 2       -> 1 2 -
1 - 2 * 3   -> 1 2 3 * -
(1 - 2) * 3 -> 1 2 - 3 *
```

Постфиксная запись обходится без скобок. Вычислить значение выражения в такой записи можно с помощью стековой машины. Для записи `1 2 3 * -` последовательность действий будет такой:

```
токен стек     комментарий
      []       в начале стек пуст
1     [1]      число 1 кладем в стек
2     [1 2]    число 2 кладем в стек
3     [1 2 3]  число 3 кладем в стек
*     [1 6]    выбираем из стека два числа и кладём назад их произведение
-     [-5]     выбираем из стека два числа и кладём назад их разность
```

На Java можно уложится в сотню строк. На Python думаю что пятидесяти хватит.

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробывать приравнивать к числовой переменной до того как выдаст исключение из-за + или - оператора, потом сохранить его в стринг переменную, а потом следующее число просто до конца сохранить в числовую переменную, а потом просто условие, если переменная стринг равняется + или минус, то мы выполняем операцию с result = num1 + num2.
Как то так.

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(inp):
    res = []
    n = 0
    for i in range(len(inp)):
        if inp[i] in ("+", "-", "*", "/"):
            res.append(int(inp[n:i]))
            res.append(inp[i])
            n = i + 1
    res.append(int(inp[i:]))
    
    return res
```

данный код разделяет строку на части, к примеру `5 * 6 / 7` он превратит в `[5, "*", 6, "/", 7]`

Answer (score 2):

Вот самый функциональный калькулятор:

```py
import os
os.system("bc")
```

и пользоваться не опасно.