# Задача со строками

Tags: c++, строки, char

Ввести выражение с клавиатуры, состоящее из четырех арифметических знаков, без пробелов и скобок. Посчитать его.

Я написал это:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <locale.h>
 
void main()
{
    char input[100], *p, zn[] = "*/+-";
    double sum = 0;
    puts("Enter:");
    gets_s(input);
    p = strtok(input, zn);
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        std::cout << atoi(p) << "\n";
        p = strtok(NULL, zn);
    }
}
```

Что делать дальше не понимаю.

Как быть с тем, что умножение и деление должны считаться первыми? И как выделить конкретные значения и провести между ними конкретную операцию?

Comment: Я правильно понял, что вам нужно реализовать простой калькулятор? Если да, то почитайте про алгоритм `обратная польская нотация` или `RPN`.

Comment: Вот тут расписан дизайн калькулятора: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217030/416121).