# Упростить код на Python

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Рябят, кто сможет покритиковать / помочь упростить монстрообразный код - изучаю питон, сейчас сделал задание по функциям, делал сам, но ощущаю, что код не лаконичный, наверняка можно было сделать проще, но не могу сообразить как, видимо не хватает знаний.

Задание:
Напишите программу, которая принимает арифметическое выражение в качестве аргумента и выводит результат этого выражения.

Примечание:
Необходимо использовать функции. Программа должна поддерживать следующие арифметические операции: +, -, /, *, %(получение процента от числа), **(возведение в квадрат), **х(возведение в степень числа х). Запрещено подключать дополнительные модули. Для вывода результата необходимо использовать функцию print().

Значения для самостоятельной проверки:
Подставьте "Входные данные" в свою программу и сравните результат с выходными данными.

1. Входные данные: 1+9.
   Выходные значения: 10.
2. Входные данные: 100%.
   Выходные значения: 1.0.
3. Входные данные: 4**.
   Выходные значения: 16.
4. Входные данные: 9**3.
   Выходные значения: 729.

Вот именно из-за 2 и 3 пункта пришлось делать именно так, как я написал т.к. получается, что мы передаем в функцию выражение: "100%", на выходе должно быть 1.0, т.е. получается, что передаем число и оператор, а второго числа нет и просто вывести результат выражения, как с 1 пунктом не получается. Конечно, если бы в функцию отдельно передавались числа и оператор как аргументы через запятую, то все было бы куда проще, я бы сразу условие написал, если оператор такой, значит делаем так, если второго аргумента нет, значит делаем так, но условие вот такое и код получился длинный:
Ссылка на гитхаб: https://github.com/Magva7/Python_my_progs/blob/main/function/calc_func.py

```py
# vyrajenie = '1+9'

# vyrajenie = '11-99'
vyrajenie = '11/2'
# vyrajenie = '4**'
# vyrajenie = '9**3'
# vyrajenie = '100%3'
# vyrajenie = '100%'

vvod_str = str(vyrajenie)

vvod_list = list(vyrajenie)  # переводим введенное выражение в списокр

def calc(vyrajenie):
    if vvod_list.count('+') != 0:  # проверяем, если ли в списке элемент +
        plus(vyrajenie)  # запускаем функцию plus
    elif vvod_list.count('-') != 0:  # проверяем, если ли в списке элемент +
        minus(vyrajenie)  # запускаем функцию минус
    elif vvod_list.count('/') != 0:  # проверяем, если ли в списке элемент /
        delenie(vyrajenie)  # запускаем функцию деление
    elif vvod_list.count('*') != 0:  # проверяем, если ли в списке элемент *
        umnoj_stepen(vyrajenie)  # запускаем функцию umnoj_stepen
    elif vvod_list.count('%') != 0:  # проверяем, если ли в списке элемент %
        ostatok(vyrajenie)  # запускаем функцию ostatok

def plus(vyrajenie):  # передали в функцию введенное выражение
    if vvod_list.count('+') != 0:  # проверяем, если ли в списке элемент +
        index_operator = vvod_list.index('+')  # записываем индекс элемента-оператора +
        sleva = ''
        sprava = ''
        i = 0
        while i < index_operator:  # до тех пор, пока у нас индекс текущего элемента меньше
            # индекса элемента, который оператор (это элемент, который +, * или что-то другое)
            sleva += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что справа элементы до оператора
            i += 1

        i += 1
        while i < len(vvod_list):  # до тех пор пока i меньше длины списка, т.е. до
        # последнего элемента
            sprava += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что слева элементы после оператора
            i += 1
        result = int(sleva)+int(sprava)
        print(result)
    return result

def minus(vyrajenie):  # передали в функцию введенное выражение
    if vvod_list.count('-') != 0:  # проверяем, если ли в списке элемент -
        index_operator = vvod_list.index('-')  # записываем индекс элемента-оператора -
        sleva = ''
        sprava = ''
        i = 0
        while i < index_operator:  # до тех пор, пока у нас индекс текущего элемента меньше
            # индекса элемента, который оператор (это элемент, который +, * или что-то другое)
            sleva += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что справа элементы до оператора
            i += 1

        i += 1
        while i < len(vvod_list):  # до тех пор пока i меньше длины списка, т.е. до
        # последнего элемента
            sprava += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что слева элементы после оператора
            i += 1
        result = int(sleva)-int(sprava)
        print(result)
    return result

def delenie(vyrajenie):  # передали в функцию введенное выражение
    if vvod_list.count('/') != 0:  # проверяем, если ли в списке элемент -
        index_operator = vvod_list.index('/')  # записываем индекс элемента-оператора -
        sleva = ''
        sprava = ''
        i = 0
        while i < index_operator:  # до тех пор, пока у нас индекс текущего элемента меньше
            # индекса элемента, который оператор (это элемент, который +, * или что-то другое)
            sleva += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что справа элементы до оператора
            i += 1

        i += 1
        while i < len(vvod_list):  # до тех пор пока i меньше длины списка, т.е. до
        # последнего элемента
            sprava += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что слева элементы после оператора
            i += 1
        result = int(sleva)/int(sprava)
        print(result)
    return result

def umnoj_stepen(vyrajenie):  # передали в функцию введенное выражение
    if vvod_list.count('*') != 0:  # проверяем, если ли в списке элемент *
        index_operator = vvod_list.index('*')  # записываем индекс элемента-оператора *
        if vvod_list[index_operator+1] == '*':  # если следующий за ним элемент тоже *,
        # значит у нас возведение в степень
            sleva = ''
            sprava = ''
            i = 0
            while i < index_operator:  # до тех пор, пока у нас индекс текущего элемента меньше
                # индекса элемента, который оператор (это элемент, который первая *)
                sleva += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что справа элементы до оператора
                i += 1
            i += 2
            while i < len(vvod_list):  # до тех пор пока i меньше длины списка, т.е. до
                # последнего элемента
                sprava += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что слева элементы после
                # второго оператора *
                i += 1
            if sprava != '':  # если у нас справа не пусто, значит у нас возведение в
        # степень одного числа на другое
                result = int(sleva) ** int(sprava)
            else:  # если же справа пусто, значит мы возводим число справа в квадрат
                result = int(sleva) ** 2

        else:  # если следующий за ним элемент не тоже *, значит у нас просто умножение
            sprava = ''
            sleva = ''
            i = 0
            while i < index_operator:  # до тех пор, пока у нас индекс текущего элемента меньше
                # индекса элемента, который оператор (это элемент, который первая *)
                sprava += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что справа элементы до оператора
                i += 1
            i += 1
            while i < len(vvod_list):  # до тех пор пока i меньше длины списка, т.е. до
                # последнего элемента
                sleva += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что слева элементы после
                # второго оператора *
                i += 1
            result = int(sprava) * int(sleva)
        # print('sprava = ', sprava)
        # print('sleva = ', sleva)
        print(result)
    return result

def ostatok(vyrajenie):  # передали в функцию введенное выражение
    if vvod_list.count('%') != 0:  # проверяем, если ли в списке элемент *
        index_operator = vvod_list.index('%')  # записываем индекс элемента-оператора *
        sleva = ''
        sprava = ''
        i = 0
        while i < index_operator:  # до тех пор, пока у нас индекс текущего элемента меньше
            # индекса элемента, который оператор (это элемент, который %)
            sleva += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что справа элементы до оператора
            i += 1
        i += 1
        while i < len(vvod_list):  # до тех пор пока i меньше длины списка, т.е. до
            # последнего элемента
            sprava += vvod_list[i]  # мы добавляем в то, что слева элементы после
            # второго оператора *
            i += 1
        if sprava != '':  # если у нас справа не пусто, значит у нас остаток от
            # деления одного числа на другоев
            result = float(sleva) % float(sprava)
        else:  # если же справа пусто, значит делаем остаток числа от самого себя
            result = float(sleva) / float(sleva)
        print(result)
    return result

calc(vyrajenie)  # запускаем нашу функцию
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1216818/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python/1217030#1217030

Comment: В исходном выражении только допустима одна операция? Т.е. что-то типа `1+2*3-4` не введут?

Comment: Да, операция только одна.

Answer (score 3):

По мотивам вашего кода попытался написать код разбора выражения просто и лаконично, используя максимально простые конструкции языка.

```
SYMBOLS = '+-*/%'               # поддерживаемые операции
DIGITS = '1234567890'           # цифры
ACCEPTABLE = SYMBOLS + DIGITS   # вообще допустимые символы во входной строке

def calc(text):
    groups = []  # сюда будем группировать символы операндов и операции
    for char in text:
        if char not in ACCEPTABLE:   # игнорируем недопустимые символы
            continue
        if (len(groups)==0 or 
            (char in DIGITS  and groups[-1][-1] in SYMBOLS) or
            (char in SYMBOLS and groups[-1][-1] in DIGITS)
           ): # создаём новую группу при смене символа с цифры на операцию (и обратно)
          groups.append([char])  
        else: # иначе дописываем к последней группе
          groups[-1].append(char)

    if len(groups) < 2 or len(groups) > 3:  # допустимые операции состоят из 2 или 3 элементов
        return None                         # так что выходим если это не так
    
    for i in range(len(groups)):            # так как groups содержит списки символов
        groups[i] = ''.join(groups[i])      # собираем их в строки
    
    operator = groups[1]                    # операция всегда в первом элементе списка

    if operator not in ['+','-','*','/','**','%']: # проверяем на допустимость операции
        return None                                # и выходим если неизвестная операция
    
    left = int(groups[0])                   # левый операнд в нулевом элементе списка
    
    if len(groups) == 2 and operator == '**':      # упростим себе жизнь добавив правый операнд
        groups.append('2')                         # для возведения в квадрат 
    
    if len(groups) == 3:
        right = int(groups[2])              # правый операнд во втором элементе списка
        if   operator == "+" :  return left +  right
        elif operator == "-" :  return left -  right
        elif operator == "*" :  return left *  right
        elif operator == "/" :  return left /  right
        elif operator == "%" :  return left %  right
        elif operator == "**":  return left ** right
        else:                   return None
    
    elif operator == '%':
        return float(left) / 100
```

Но если кратко, то нижеприведённая лямбда-функция считает то же самое. Только что на ошибки не проверяет.

```
calc = lambda t: eval(t+'2' if t[-1]=='*' else t[:-1]+'/100' if t[-1]=='%' else t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверки на соответствие формату +уведомления

```
VR = list('1+9')
# VR = list('100%')
# VR = list('4**')
# VR = list('9**3')
# VR = list('19/3')

SYMBOLS = list('+-*/%')               # поддерживаемые операции
DIGITS = list('1234567890')           # цифры

def exception(s):
    if s == 0:
        n='Не допустимый символ'
    if s == 1:
        n='Не допустимый формат операции'
    if s == 2:
        n='Нет арифметической операции ' + ', '.join(SYMBOLS)
    print (n)
    exit ()

def calc(s): # проверив что все соответствует формату считаем средставами питона
    cmd = r'print({})'.format( "".join(map(str, s)) )
    exec(cmd)

def format(x,z): #проверки по формату
    ACCEPTABLE=SYMBOLS.copy()
    ACCEPTABLE.extend(DIGITS)            # все поддерживаемые
    index_max=len(VR)-1
    for char in VR:
        if ACCEPTABLE.count(char) == 0: #проверяем поддерживаемые операции
            exception(0)
            
    if x == '%' and z == 1 and VR[index_max] == '%':
        print ('%(получение процента от числа)')
        VR.pop() #удаляем последний символ 
        n = float("".join(map(str, VR))) / 100
        print (n)
    elif (x in '+' '-' '/' '*') and z == 1 and (VR[0] in DIGITS) and (VR[index_max] in DIGITS):
        print('(операции +-/*)')
        n=calc(VR)
    elif x == '*' and z == 2:
        if (VR[index_max] in DIGITS):
            print('**х(возведение в степень числа х)')
            n=calc(VR)    
        else:
            print('**(возведение в квадрат)')
            VR.append(2) #добавляем 2 для простоты 
            n=calc(VR)
    else:
        exception(1)

def solve(VR):
    сountchar=0
    for char in SYMBOLS:
        if VR.count(char) > 0: #проверяем поддерживаемые операции
            сountchar+=1 
            format(char, VR.count(char)) # какое действие выполняется, формат выражения 
            break
    if сountchar < 1:
        exception(2)

solve(VR)
```

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку тут инспекция кода и никто не обратил внимание на это, то добавлю замечания не относящиеся к логике. Все рекомендации взяты из PEP.

1. Первое, что бросается в глаза - это конечно же комментарии на каждой строке. Так делать не надо по нескольким причинам:

   - затрудняется чтение самого кода
   - очень часто не соблюдается длина строки в 79 символов [PEP 8 - максимальная рекомендованная длина](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)
   - так же в PEP 8 указано, что длина строк документации не должна превышать 72 символа
     Для понимания, как комментировать код на python существует [PEP 257 (en)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0257/), [PEP 257 (ru)](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/dokumentirovanie-koda-v-python-pep-257.html)
2. Безбожный нэйминг, честно, переменные и функции не надо называть в транслите, функцию начните с глагола (что делает?). Примеры:

   - `vvod_str` -> `input_str`
   - `vyrajenie` -> `expression`
   - `plus` -> `add`
     За тем, как это соблюдать, обращаемся снова к документации [PEP 8 (en)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/), [PEP 8 (ru)](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/pep-8-rukovodstvo-po-napisaniyu-koda-na-python.html)
3. Еще обратил внимание на функцию `print()` внутри ваших функций. Есть такое понятие - **чистая функция**, под которым понимаются функции, не производящие никаких наблюдаемых побочных эффектов, только возвращающие результат. То есть, есть только вход и выход, и нет стандартного ввода или вывода, нет измений объектов выше зоны видимости самой функции (не трогают глобальные переменные и не изменяют их) и т. д. Если убрать из функций `print()` и сделать их *чистыми*, то результат работы функции надо выводить через стандартный вывод, т.е.

```py
print(calc(vyrajenie))
```

4. Если в функции существует вариант, когда функция ничего не возвращает, то необходимо явно указывать `None`. Возьму для примера вашу `ostatok()`

```py
def ostatok(vyrajenie):  # передали в функцию введенное выражение
    if vvod_list.count('%') != 0:
    .....
            result = float(sleva) / float(sleva)
        return result
    else:
        return None
```

Опять же данный пункт относится к [PEP 8 рекомендации](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Вообще, существует расширения для множества IDE, которые позволяют не задумываться о соблюдении указанных выше моментов. Их просто надо установить и использовать.

По логике, остальные ответы раскрывают ваше тему.

**UPD**

Решил добавить свой вариант для python 3.10 с конструкцией `match-case`. Цель была показать возможность использования

```py
def prepare_input(user_input:str):
    symbols = "+-/*"
    result = {}
    for symbol in symbols:
        if symbol in user_input:
            operation = symbol
    user_list = user_input.split(operation)
    if len(user_list) == 2:
        try:
            result["operation"] = operation
            result["left"] = int(user_list[0].strip())
            result["right"] = int(user_list[1].strip())
            return result
        except:
            print("inncorrect input")
    else:
        return None


def calculate(values:dict):
    if values:
        operation, a, b = values["operation"], values["left"], values["right"]
        match operation:
            case "+": return a + b
            case "-": return a - b
            case "*": return a * b
            case "/": return a / b
            case _: return None
    else:
        return None

# tests
a = ["10 + 11", "10 / 11", "10 - 11", "10 * 11"]

for i in a:
    expression = prepare_input(i)
    print(calculate(expression))
```

Answer (score 0):

Я вот так вот писал шифратор и дешифратор,обрати внимание на часть которую я выделил,не уверен что тебе может помочь,но это может упростить твое решение . Если ты сразу спросишь че надо делать. По заданию впрн тебе надо спросить изначально,что надо, а потом в зависимости от этого,чтобы код пошел по той или иной ветке решения
Заранее извини,если это не поможет. Я только начинаю.Но стараюсь

```
***slov = int(input("Введи количество слов которые надо либо зашифровать или расшифровать:"))
while slov > 0:
    slov-=1
    cryptMode = input("Выбери че хочешь делать: [Ш]ифрование|[Д]ешифрование: ").upper()
    if cryptMode not in ['Ш', 'Д']:
        print("Ошибка, режим не найден!")
        raise SystemExit***

    startMessage = input("Введите сообщение: ").upper()
    keyMessage = input("Введите номер ключа: ")
    def encryptdecrypt(mode, message, key, final=""):
        key *= len(message) // len(key) + 1
        for index, symbol in enumerate(message):
            if mode == 'Ш':
                temp = ord(symbol) + int(key[index]) - 1
            else:
                temp = ord(symbol) - int(key[index]) - 9
            final += chr(temp % 30 + ord('А'))
        return final

    
    print("Final message:", encryptdecrypt(cryptMode, startMessage, keyMessage))
    print("жмакай Enter!")
    k=input("Пожалуйста,без пробелов ,по слову вводи")
```

Comment: Как это поможет ТС?

Comment: По сравнению с вашим ответом,то я полностью согласен,что код,который я прислал как пример,не целесообразный для решения данного вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Напишите программу, которая принимает арифметическое выражение в качестве аргумента и выводит результат этого выражения.

в качестве извлечения математического оператора используем метод "split" для строк

ограничения: только один арифметический знак в строке, нет проверок на  недопустимые символы

```
def simplyCalc(expr):
    new=[]
    for char in expr:
        if char =='*':
            if expr.find('*') != expr.rfind('*'): #если встретили знак умножения "*", то проверяем, что он единственный
                new=expr.split('**')
                num1=int(new[0])
                if new[1].isdigit(): #если после '**' нет цифры, то понимаем, что это возведение в квадрат
                    num2 =int(new[1])
                else:
                    num2 =2
                x = num1**num2
            else:    
                new=expr.split('*')
                num1=int(new[0])
                num2 =int(new[1])
                x=num1*num2        
        elif char =='+':
            new=expr.split('+')
            num1 = int(new[0])
            num2 = int(new[1])
            x = num1+num2
        elif char =='-':
            new=expr.split('-')
            num1 = int(new[0])
            num2 = int(new[1])
            x = num1-num2
        elif char =='/':
            new=expr.split('/')
            num1 = int(new[0])
            num2 = int(new[1])
            x = num1/num2            
        elif char =='%':
            new=expr.split('%')
            num1 = int(new[0])
            x=float(num1) / 100       
    return x

s = '11%'
print(simplyCalc(s))

print('-----End------')
```

Comment: это ответ или новый вопрос?

Comment: предполагается, что это ответ )