# Построение функции

Tags: python, функции

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задание решил следующим образом:

```
def func(n):
        acc='+*%-/'
        n1=str(n)
        n2=list(n1)
        n3=''.join(n2 for n2 in n1 if n2 in acc)
        if n3=='%':
                n4=n2.remove('%')
                n5=''.join(i for i in n2)
                answer=int(n5)/100
                return answer
        if n3=='+':
                t=n2.index('+')
                n4=''.join(i for i in n2[0:t])
                n5=''.join(i for i in n2[t+1:])
                answer=int(n4)+int(n5)
                return answer
        if n3=='-':
                t=n2.index('-')
                n4=''.join(i for i in n2[0:t])
                n5=''.join(i for i in n2[t+1:])
                answer=int(n4)-int(n5)
                return answer
        if n3=='/':
                t=n2.index('/')
                n4=''.join(i for i in n2[0:t])
                n5=''.join(i for i in n2[t+1:])
                answer=int(n4)/int(n5)
                return answer
        if n3=='*':
                t=n2.index('*')
                n4=''.join(i for i in n2[0:t])
                n5=''.join(i for i in n2[t+1:])
                answer=int(n4)*int(n5)
                return answer
        if n3=='**':
                t=n2.index('*')
                if len(n2)-t>2:
                        n4=int(''.join(i for i in n2[:t]))
                        n5=int(''.join(i for i in n2[t+2:]))
                        answer=n4**n5
                        return answer
                else:
                        n4=int(''.join(i for i in n2[:t]))
                        answer=n4**2
                        return answer
```

Есть иное(более компактное) решение для данного задания?
Мой код решает арифметическое выражение только с двумя числами. Каким образом написать код для трех и более?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: И что вам всем задают [одно и то же](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1333065/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python/)...

Comment: То что задают одно и то же не удивляет. Больше удивляет, что никто поиском не пользуется

Comment: @GrAnd Спасибо. А в чем логика условия if в строках 10-16 в вашем ответе? Если длина groups 0, зачем остальные два условия и в чем смысл groups[-1][-1]?

Comment: `groups[-1][-1]` - последний символ последней группы. Проверяется что его "тип" отличается от "типа" текущего символа. Эти условия как раз проверяются когда длина _groups_ не равна 0 (т.е. есть чего проверять). Если длина равна 0, то это условие срабатывает и так.