# Как ввести и вывести многочлен(Python)

Tags: python

У меня стоит задача написать алгоритм схемы Горнера для вычисления многочлена. Мне нужно ввести многочлен вида `2+3*x-6*x^2+4*x^3`. Как я могу ввести его и потом вывести в таком же виде для проверки без использования дополнительных библиотек?

Comment: Вводите и выводите как строку.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Пробовал, потом, когда нужно совершать действия с ними, пишет, что нельзя такие действия совершать со строкой, а привести к другому типу данных это выражение тоже не получается

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1216818/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python/1217030#1217030

Comment: Берусь превратить строку в многочлен за 40 строк. Даже меньше.

Comment: А что мешает держать список коэффициентов при степенях [2,3,-6,4] ? Выводить его в строку вида `2+3*x-6*x^2+4*x^3` несложно